# There has been an error processing your request in Backend Magento

Tags: magento2

He creado un modulo de Magento 2.4.2 para sincronizar magento con channeladvisor, lo instalo y todo esta bien pero al entrar al backend para configurar los datos de acceso me da el siguiente error

```
**Param resource doesn't pass validation: 'ProductCA::productca_menu' does not match against pattern '/^[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]+_[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9]+::[A-Za-z_0-9]+$/'**
```

este es el codigo de mi menu.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
<menu>
    <add id="ProductCA::productca_menu" title="ProductCA" module="ProductCA" sortOrder="10" resource="ProductCA::productca_menu"/>
    <add id="ProductCA::productca_sync" title="Sync Products" module="ProductCA" sortOrder="10" parent="ProductCA::productca_menu" action="productca/sync/index" resource="ProductCA::productca_sync"/>
</menu>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
            <resource id="ProductCA::productca_menu" title="ProductCA" sortOrder="10">
                <resource id="ProductCA::productca_sync" title="Sync Products" sortOrder="10" />
            </resource>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

Lo he cambiado, rehecho... reestructurado y sigo tieniendo el mismo error.....

pueden ayuidarme?

Answer (score -1):

¿Tienes configurado correctamente tu archivo acl.xml? Debes tenerlo en este formato:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                        <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                            <resource id="GersonHernandez_HelloWorld::config_gersonhernandez_helloworld" title="mysection"/>
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Luego tu archivo menu.xml debe tener el siguiente formato:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="GersonHernandez::top_level" title="GersonHernandez" module="GersonHernandez_HelloWorld" sortOrder="9999" resource="GersonHernandez_HelloWorld::config_gersonhernandez_helloworld"/>
        <add id="GersonHernandez_HelloWorld::gersonhernandez_helloworld_blog" title="Blog" module="GersonHernandez_HelloWorld" sortOrder="9999" resource="GersonHernandez_HelloWorld::config_gersonhernandez_helloworld" parent="GersonHernandez::top_level" action="gersonhernandez_helloworld/blog/index"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Comment: Por favor, evita las firmas y la autopromocion...